# What's wrong with this step? $\lim_{x \to 1} = \dfrac{a^{(1-x)}-1}{1-x}$

Tags: limits

so I have this limit. $$\lim_{x \to 1} = \dfrac{a^{(1-x)}-1}{1-x}$$

I've already worked out the answer is $\ln(a)$ using L'hopital's rule but before I tried it I tried to simplify it with this step;

$$\lim_{x \to 1} = \dfrac{a^{(1-x)}-1[+1]}{1-x[+1]}=\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{a^{(1-x)}}{2-x}=1$$

Now I know this isn't valid because L'hopital's rule yields a different answer, but I can't actually explain why it's not valid, so could anyone explain why please?

Thanks.

Comment: because in general, $\frac{a}{b}\ne \frac{a+1}{b+1}$

Comment: In general, $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\neq \frac{\alpha+1}{\beta+1}$ ($\beta\neq 0$ and $\beta\neq -1$). It is easily seen with $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=2$, since $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\neq \frac{2}{3}=\frac{\alpha+1}{\beta+1}$.

Comment: Um, do you seriously not know that $\frac ab \ne \frac {a+c}{b+c} $?

Comment: I understand why it's not, but I haven't had much actual practice so I just forget these things. I'm 28 and I've only been learning maths for 1 year prior to my university course since leaving school, so it's just hard to remember all this stuff. I'm trying my best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding $1$ to the numerator and denominator of a fraction is not a legitimate move. If it were, we would have:

$$\frac12 = \frac{1+1}{2+1}=\frac23$$

Indeed, it is valid to *mutiply* the numerator and denominator by the same (nonzero) quantity, but not to add something to them. It's because fractions are essentially "made of" multiplication and division, not addition and subtraction.